# Panda combine multiple rows into one row with different column names not in one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file -

CSV A-

```
    Date/Time             Num
2023/04/10 14:13:18      6122
2023/04/10 14:14:24      6005
2023/04/10 14:14:59      6004
```

There will be 3 rows max or less then that, also Num=6122 will be there always. The other two numbers(6005 & 6004) rows may or may not be there.

Output I am looking for-

```
    Date/Time             Num       Date/Time_1          Num_1      Date/Time_2          Num_2
2023/04/10 14:13:18      6122   2023/04/10 14:14:24      6005   2023/04/10 14:14:59      6004
```

If Num=6005, then the date/time and number should be in 3rd and 4th column, if Num=6004 then the date/time and number should be in 5th and 6th column, otherwise leave it empty like below -

```
    Date/Time             Num       Date/Time_1      Num_1        Date/Time_2           Num_2
2023/04/10 14:13:18      6122                                   2023/04/10 14:14:59      6004
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
import numpy as np

cols = np.ravel([df.columns + (f'_{i}' if i else '') for i in range(len(df))])
out = pd.DataFrame([np.ravel(df)], columns=cols)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
             Date/Time   Num          Date/Time_1  Num_1          Date/Time_2  Num_2
0  2023/04/10 14:13:18  6122  2023/04/10 14:14:24   6005  2023/04/10 14:14:59   6004
```

**Update**

> What if number 6005 is not there, in that case it will set the 6004 number row at 3rd and 4th column but I want it to be 5th and 6th column and 3rd - 4th column will be empty?

You can hard code the transformation:

```
pd.concat([df[df['Num'] == 6122].reset_index(drop=True),
           df[df['Num'] == 6005].add_suffix('_1').reset_index(drop=True),
           df[df['Num'] == 6004].add_suffix('_2').reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)

# Output
             Date/Time   Num Date/Time_1  Num_1          Date/Time_2  Num_2
0  2023/04/10 14:13:18  6122         NaN    NaN  2023/04/10 14:14:59   6004
```

To inject this row in a database, you can try to convert `NaT/NaN` to None with:

```
# out = pd.concat(...)
out = out.replace({pd.NaT: None, np.NaN: None})
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it's working fine if we have all three numbers i.e. 6122, 6005, 6004. What if number 6005 is not there, in that case it will set the 6004 number row at 3rd and 4th column but I want it to be 5th and 6th column and 3rd - 4th column will be empty? Updated the answer above

Comment: it's working fine. Thank you for the quick response. I need one more help to insert this value in DB. I am having issues to store the NaN into datetime field in postgresDB. Tried multiple ways but nothing worked. Can you please suggest how to insert NaN or empty value in datetime field in postgres ?

Comment: @RKIDEV you misunderstood how this site works. This is not a free consulting service to help you solve your issues. Stackoverflow is rather a database of Q/A that should be helpful to everyone. So please keep your questions focused, stick to one topic, don't change them after you got valid answers.

Answer (score 3):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then convert [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_frame.html), [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) and [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html). Finally flatten the MultiIndex:

```
out = df.stack().to_frame().T.swaplevel(axis=1)

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
```

Output:

```
           Date/Time_0 Num_0          Date/Time_1 Num_1          Date/Time_2 Num_2
0  2023/04/10 14:13:18  6122  2023/04/10 14:14:24  6005  2023/04/10 14:14:59  6004
```

If you don't want the `_0`:

```
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{"_"+str(x[1]) if x[1] else ""}')
```

Output:

```
             Date/Time   Num          Date/Time_1 Num_1          Date/Time_2 Num_2
0  2023/04/10 14:13:18  6122  2023/04/10 14:14:24  6005  2023/04/10 14:14:59  6004
```

##### forcing a particular order and inserting NaNs if needed

Assuming this input:

```
             Date/Time   Num
0  2023/04/10 14:13:18  6122
1  2023/04/10 14:14:59  6004
```

You can force reindexing with a dictionary and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), before applying the above method:

```
order = [6122, 6005, 6004]

d = {k: v for v,k in enumerate(order)}

out = (df.set_axis(df['Num'].map(d)).reindex(d.values())
         .stack(dropna=False).to_frame().T.swaplevel(axis=1)
      )
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}{"_"+str(x[1]) if x[1] else ""}')
```

Output:

```
             Date/Time     Num Date/Time_1 Num_1          Date/Time_2   Num_2
0  2023/04/10 14:13:18  6122.0         NaN   NaN  2023/04/10 14:14:59  6004.0
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it's working fine if we have all three numbers i.e. 6122, 6005, 6004. What if number 6005 is not there, in that case it will set the 6004 number row at 3rd and 4th column but I want it to be 5th and 6th column and 3rd - 4th column will be empty? Updated the answer above

Comment: Then you need to mask the values before stacking